# AES_cfb128_encrypt and decrypt using openssl command

Tags: c, unix, encryption, openssl, cryptography

I am encrypting a data file using below openssl function

```
KEY="123456KEY";
IVEC="123456IVEC"

AES_set_encrypt_key(KEY, 128, &key);
AES_cfb128_encrypt(indata, outdata, bytes_read, &key, IVEC, &num, AES_ENCRYPT);
```

As a result I have encrypted file **file.tgz.enc**, I can decrypt this file using same *AES_cfb128_encrypt(AES_DECRYPT)* function, but I want to decrypt this file using command line openssl command. I am trying like

```
======
COMMAND
======
/usr/bin/openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -d -in file.tgz.enc -out
new-file.tgz -K 123456KEY -iv 123456IVEC
======
OUTPUT
======
non-hex digit
invalid hex iv value
```

I am getting error on command line, like *non-hex digit, invalid hex iv value* and I am unable to decrypt the file.
any idea ? Can some one guide me ?

Comment: The key and iv used with `AES_cfb128_encrypt` are too small. They need to be 16 bytes. Effectively, the missing half of the key and iv are random bytes.

Comment: You should *not* use `AES_encrypt` and friends. That's a software-only implementation, so you will not enjoy hardware support, like AES-NI. You should be using `EVP_*` functions. See [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki. In fact, you should probably be using authenticated encryption because it provides *both* confidentiality and authenticity. See [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Answer (score 1):

-K and -iv expects hex character and the input you specified has non hex characters `K` and `Y` in `123456KEY` and `I` and `V` in `123456IVEC`

You need pass proper 16 byte key to `AES_cfb128_encrypt` and initialization vector to  `AES_cfb128_encrypt`
But KEY has only 9 bytes, if size of KEY(variable) is 9 too, it is likely to result into undefined behavior as `AES_set_encrypt_key` will go on reading 128 bites(16 bytes) from KEY

Whichever key and IV you use in your code, you need to take its hex representation and use it in openssl command tool

Comment: that was very helpful reply Pras,
I made changes to program and made the KEY=0 and IVEC=0 and then I am decrypting the file using command line like

`openssl aes-128-cbc -K 0 -iv 0 -d -in file.tgz.enc -out new-file.tgz`

still i am getting error

**bad decrypt
140428822333344:error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length:evp_enc.c:597:**

Comment: Why dont you pass some values eg strcpy(KEY,"0123456789ABCDEF");strcpy(IVEC,"FEDCBA9876543210"); in code then in command 30313233343536373839414243444546 as key and 46454443424139383736353433323130 iv